Setting up VS Code with msys2/ucrt64
I've been trying to set up my VS Code for C++ using the g++ compiler with the tutorial on the VS Code website. Whenever I try to debug the code, this error message is showing:


I:

checked all g++, gcc, gdb, --version in the terminal, and they're installed already
Added path to my environment variables
installed C/C++ extensions on VS Code.


the task "terminal" output shows Build finished with errors, find out the errors, the compiler fails not the debugger, copy the build command to a regular terminal

The message says Please run the 'Select IntelliSense Configuration...' command.  What happened when you did that?

I'm asked to choose a compiler there and I tried choosing both use g++ and gcc compiler which I have in C:msys64/ucrt64/bin but still the same errors afterwards.

Does a simple "Hello World" program compile using the method in the official VSCode MinGW documentation that uses a tasks.json?

Also did you write a tasks.json for this or did you attempt to use code-runner and modify your settings.json. I recommend forgetting that code-runner exists for c++ based projects. Instead use a tasks.json or CMake and the VSCode CMakeTools extension when your projects get more advanced.

the json files only got built after I tried fidgeting around with settings and I might've tried using code runner once but that was after the error so not the case of my problem. I simply tried to follow the vscode tutorial I attached in the post above.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
